# How to run mono commands in msysgit?

Tags: command-line, mono, msysgit

I am having trouble running mono CLI commands inside the msysgit console. It works fine in the windows command prompt added by the Mono installer. I have paid attention to the `path` env variable in the mono command prompt and added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\bin\;` to the beginning of my system path (and restarted msysgit).

I am getting the following error when trying to run `xbuild`:

`/c/Program Files (x86)/Mono/bin/xbuild: line 2: cygpath: command not found Cannot open assembly 'xbuild.exe': No such file or directory.`

What am I missing from msysgit to help mono's CLI tools work better?

Comment: Does mono-sgen.exe --version work? The commands such as xbuild etc. are just shell script wrappers, so better rule out that first.

Answer (score 1):

Mono for windows is built with cygwin + mingw ([see Mono compile guide](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/windows/)).
I'm not sure whether it's fully compatible with msys or not. From the error, I guess there is a problem of path. You may need **cygpath.exe** in your path from the [following link](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/binsh-cygpath-command-not-found/28965.html). You should probably invoke mono either from Cygwin or cmd (through the bat provided files).
Even if mono for windows is compiled with mingw (and thus should not depend on cygwin), from your error, we can see there are still cygwin dependencies.